# Does $(X)(Y)=(XY)$ for $X,Y\subseteq R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, examples-counterexamples

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Denote by $X\ast Y=\{xy\mid x\in X,y\in Y\}$ the complex product of subsets. I want to show that given subsets $X,Y\subseteq R$ the following ideals are equal: $$(X)(Y)=(X\ast Y)\,.$$
By defnition, $(X)(Y)=((X)\ast(Y))$, so I have to show that

- $X\ast Y\subseteq((X)\ast(Y))$,
- $(X)\ast(Y)\subseteq(X\ast Y)$.

The first point is trivial, because $X\subseteq(X)$ and $Y\subseteq(Y)$ implies $$X\ast Y\subseteq(X)\ast(Y)\subseteq((X)\ast(Y))\,.$$

As for the second point, let $a=\sum_i r_ix_i\in(X)$ and $b=\sum_js_jy_j\in (Y)$. Then $$ab=\sum_{i,j}r_ix_is_jy_j=\sum_{i,j}r_is_jx_iy_j\in(X\ast Y)\,,$$ which proves 2..

I have two questions:

> 1. Is my proof of the above assertion correct?
> 2. Does the statement still hold if $R$ is not commutative and we replace *ideal* by *left-*, *right-* or *two-sided ideal*? I think I used commutativitiy in the second step.

**Edit:** I think I have a counterexample for 2.: Let $R$ be any ring and let $R\langle x,y,z\rangle$ be the $R$-algebra freely generated by $x,y,z$. Then I think $xyz\in(x)(z)$ but $xyz\notin(xz)$. This should work when $()$ is the generated left ideal aswell as if it is the generated two-sided ideal. Is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps you want to replace the tag examples-counterexamples by solution-verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof looks right.

But I'm confused about your remark "by definition $(X)(Y) = ((X)(Y))$". It's not a definition, these sets just turn out to be equal because $R$ is commutative.

By definition, $(XY)$ is the ideal generated by $XY$. So an element in $(XY)$ is a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i x_i y_i$.

$(X)(Y)$ on the other hand, consists of elements of the form $\left ( \sum_{i=1}^n r_i x_i \right ) \left ( \sum_{j=1}^m r'_j y_j \right )$.

Regarding your example: You need to assume that $R$ is not commutative. Also, I assume you meant finitely generated rather than freely. Then: yes, indeed since $yz \in (z)$, $xyz \in (x)(z)$ but $xyz \notin (xz)$ since $R$ is assumed to be non-commutative.

Comment: The OP is saying “$(X)(Y)=((X)\ast(Y))$”, which is correct. “Freely generated” is correct as well.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @egreg Can you point me to a definition of "freely generated algebra"? I can only find "finitely generated algebra". Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer It's the free object on (in this case) three elements; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra